# How can I use the GlusterFS in Kubernetes without Heketi server?

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

I've an existing GlusterFS up and running. How can I use the GlusterFS erfs (external GlusterFS) in Kuberneteswithout heketi server?
I'm looking for Heketi server alternate as The Heketiproject is now in deep maintenance status. https://github.com/heketi/heketi

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Hekiti is used setting up dynamic volumes provisioning, in Kubernetes. Thus, how to run GlusterFS in Kubernetes without Heketi: just skip whichever step told you to deploy Heketi in the first place. It's not part of GlusterFS.

And yes, nowadays, in the context of Kubernetes: Heketi, and/or GlusterFS, should be avoided. I think they're still in the process of implementing/refactoring proper Container-Storage-Interface, which is now pretty much required setting up storage in Kubernetes.

If you're looking for block storage, Ceph / RBD is usually a good candidate. For file storage, CephFS would do. Object storage: Ceph / RadosGW.

Comment: I need to use Glusterfs for dynamic volume provisioning in kubernetes.
https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes

Comment: sure. Then you need a time machine, and install Kubernetes 1.11 or something. or get in touch with glusterfs engineering, check what's the status of their dynamic provisioner. or do this without dynamic provisioning. Although, as a former GlusterFS user: maybe you don't know it yet, but you really don't want to use GlusterFS for block storage in Kubernetes -- or in general. GlusterFS can be nice with file storage: with block, it's a nightmare. Prepare to get applications returning 500 errors, because it takes too long to write something ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try Kadalu Storage that uses core filesystem part from GlusterFS and provides storage to Kubernetes. Kadalu also supports external Gluster Volumes.

https://github.com/kadalu/kadalu

Disclaimer: I am Co-Creator and maintainer of the Kadalu Project.

Comment: Heketi has some prerequisites to use external gluster storage
*   A running GlusterFS for storing the Heketi database.
*   Available raw storage devices on GlusterFS cluster nodes.
*   SSH key to connect Heketi to GlusterFS nodes.

Similarly do we have prerequisites for Kadalu to use an external gluster storage?

Comment: how kadalu is communicating with the external gluster without providing credentials?

Comment: Kadalu mounts the external Gluster Volume. Just like any other Gluster clients, Kadalu is also a Gluster client (Mount). If the client IP is allowed by the Gluster servers (Firewall rules or IPs allow list of gluster volume set command), then the mount will succeed.